# angular 6 prime ng datatable tooltip for checkAll header checkbox

Tags: angular6, primeng-datatable

Using prime ng data table's column checkbox as,

```
<p-column [style]="{'width':'38px'}" selectionMode="multiple">                                            
</p-column>
```

I want to add a tooltip in the header to indicate a value of checkAll/uncheck All.

In stack overflow found that in prime faces we can add a tooltip how to do this in angular?

Comment: Have you tried adding pTooltip="Enter your username" tooltipPosition="top" ?

Comment: i tried this and did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add to a template, something like this:

```
<p-column [style]="{'width':'38px'}" selectionMode="multiple">  
 <ng-template pTemplate="header">
       <span pTooltip="this is a tooltip!" appendTo="target" 
                   style="position: relative">
              {{row[col.field]}}
            </span>
    </ng-template>                                          
</p-column>
```

Also make sure you imported tooltip in app.module, import {TooltipModule} from 'primeng/tooltip';